# Installing Python 3 and Alias it on a Mac

Tags: python

I was installing python 3 and following this video here on how to do it. [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YYXdXT2l-Gg) At 4:15 the video says type `nano ~/.bash_profile` Then alias python3 as python below the declaration of PATH. I did that as follows:

```
alias python=python3
```

Exactly like in the video. Then I went to check what version of python was loaded and I still have version 2.7.16.

Secondly, all of my `$` are now `%` and it is quite weird. Did I do something wrong?

Output:

```
Jack@Jacks-MBP-2 ~ % python --version
Python 2.7.16
Jack@Jacks-MBP-2 ~ % python3 --version
Python 3.8.0
Jack@Jacks-MBP-2 ~ %
```

Within `~/.bash_profile`

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.8
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

alias python=python3
```

Answer (score -1):

To be clear: is this alias within ~/.bash or ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile?

I am not familiar with MacOS but I don't believe that ~/.bash is sourced by default.

.bash_profile is sourced for login shells, but not for graphical terminals.

So try locating the command within ~/.bashrc.

Comment: Ah, ok. I added an edit for that. I don't believe that ~/.bash_profile is sourced for graphical terminals. (Rather, ~/.profile is used, and it should read ~/.bashrc.) I still think ~/.bashrc is the right place for this.